# Arrangement of dimes to bring all heads

Tags: combinatorics

Consider an arrangement of n dimes in a straight line. A move consists of taking a dime and turning it over (from head to tail or vice versa) and of doing the same to each of its neighbors. If the dime is at the end of the line, then it will have only one neighbor. For example, if the arrangement is HHTH and you choose the second dime, then your move would result in TTHH. The general question is this: Given any arrangement of n dimes, is it possible to find a sequence of moves to bring it to all heads?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this question please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The pair $TH$ already seems problematic.

Comment: What is the answer if $n=3?$

Comment: @saulspatz  for $n=3$ it can be done.  $TTT\mapsto HHH$ (flip the middle one).  $THT\mapsto HTT\mapsto HHH$, $HHT\mapsto TTT\mapsto HHH$;  $HTH \mapsto THT$ and so on.

Comment: I think it works for $n=3$ and $4$ and I would guess it works for all larger $n$

Comment: I find it hard to get intuition for larger $n$.  Naive inductions don't seem to work.  On the other hand, I don't see parity obstructions or anything of that sort.

Comment: @lulu Yes, I was asking if the OP had gotten that far.  I drew a graph.  It turns out to be a cube.  Perhaps one wants to build a graph on the n-bit binary strings to solve the general problem.

Comment: @saulspatz  for what it's worth (maybe not much!) I am skeptical that it can always be done.  That said, I haven't found a counterexample.

Comment: @lulu I started by trying to find an invariant that would demonstrate it couldn't always be done, but I haven't been able to.  I'm going to try building some bigger graphs, and seeing whether they are connected.

Comment: @saulspatz   I believe that $THTHH$ is a counterexample.  Brute force, and I could certainly be wrong.

Comment: @lulu Writing a python script to test it.

Comment: it does not work for 5

Comment: but i do not know how to write a general proof

Comment: Yes, my script shows it doesn't work for 5, but I used a brute force method that I wouldn't know how to make into a proof.

Comment: It works for 4, but not for 6.  Again, by brute force.

Comment: our professor says it works for 6 but not for 5

Comment: @GhazalBadr What I did before was to construct the adjacency matrix of the graph, and use the theorem that a [$k-$regular graph is connected if and the eigenvalue $k$ has multiplicity one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph)  Let me try something less opaque and report back.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your help  i am waiting for your reply because i did not understand what you just said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @saulspatz for the numerical evidence, without which I could not have found this proof:

For any length $k$, going from the left to the right in one pass, find the first T, flip it to H without affecting all the Hs to its left.  E.g. HHTTH -> HH(TTH) -> HH(HHT).  By doing so you are left with either all Hs (done) or all Hs except the rightmost position is T.  In the this latter case:

- if $k = 3n$, you have $3n-1$ Hs.  Go from right to left in one pass, flip non-overlapping sets of 3 coins to T, and the final set of 2 coins also to T.  Now you have all Ts.  Flip them all over to Hs, which is doable because $k=3n$.
- if $k = 3n+1$, you have $3n$ Hs.  Do the same as above to get to all Ts.  Now flip them as $2 + 3 + 3 + \cdots + 3 + 2$ back to all Hs.

The above procedure constructively proves that the problem is solvable for all $k= 3n$ or $3n+1$.

To show that $k=3n+2$ is NOT solvable first observe that in any sequence of moves, if you make the same move, i.e. at a certain position $i$, twice, their effects cancel out, EVEN IF they were done at separate (discrete) time in the sequence.  Thus any move sequence (of any length) actually boils down to a subset of all possible moves.  There are $k$ possible moves, so there are only $2^k$ subsets.  For the problem to be solvable, each subset must have a DIFFERENT effect, since there are $2^k$ possible starting positions.  However, for $k=3n+2$, the moves $3 + \cdots + 3 + 2$ and the moves $2 + 3 + \cdots + 3$ have the same effect.  So the no. of all possible effects $< 2^k$ and some starting position must be unsolvable.

**ALTERNATE VIEW:** The move at position $j$ ($1 \le j \le k$) can be modeled as a $k$-vector $v_j$ with $1$s at positions $j-1, j, j+1$ (ignore out of range entries) and $0$ everywhere else.  Then doing the $j$th move and then the $j_2$th move can be modeled as $v_j + v_{j_2}$ mod2, and doing a subset $M$ of moves can be modeled as $\sum_{j \in M} v_j$.  This suggests a matrix representation.  (Assume mod2 from now on.)

Let $A$ be the (tri-diagonal) $k \times k$ matrix where $A_{ij} = 1$ if $|i-j|\le 1$ and $0$ otherwise.  So a subset $M$ of moves can be represented as a $k$-vector $m$ where $m_j = 1$ if $j \in M$ and $0$ otherwise, and doing those moves have effect $A m$, i.e. the end result is flipping all positions $p$ where $[Am]_p = 1$.

Any given starting position can be represented by a $k$-vector $t$ where $t_j = 1$ if the $j$th position is T, and $0$ if it is H.  So solving $t$ means finding $m$ s.t. $t = Am$.  Thus, the problem is solvable for all $t$ iff $A$ has full rank, or equivalently, $det(A) \neq 0$.  Let $d_k$ be the determinant of the $k\times k$ version of the $A$ matrix.  From the structure of the tridiagonal matrices by looking at the minors, one can show $d_k = d_{k-1} + d_{k-2}$.  Staring from $d_2 = 0, d_3 = 1$ the rest of the sequences goes $1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1$ etc.  This again shows the problem is solvable (for all starting positions) iff $k = 3n$ or $3n+1$.

Further, for $k=3n+2$, while $A_{k \times k}$ does not have full rank, it contains $A_{(k-1)\times (k-1)}$ as a block, and the block has full rank, so $rank(A_{k \times k}) = k-1$.  Therefore, the number of solvable starting positions $=|range(A_{k \times k})| = 2^{k-1}$, i.e. exactly half the starting positions are solvable.

BTW here are $A^{-1}$ for $k=12$ and $13$, just for fun.  The $j$th column (or row) is how one would solve a single T at $j$.  The patterns are quite different for $3n$ and $3n+1$.

```
0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0

1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
```

Comment: I was just getting to the point where I could post a similar proof. +1

Comment: I'm in the middle of typing out my proof, although I had only got as far as proving the impossibility when $n\equiv2\pmod3.$  I just assumed I'd be able to do the other case when I'd finished.  I need to read your argument.  If mine is essentially different, I'll post it, but the first couple of sentences suggest I'm thinking along the same lines.

Comment: sorry for "scooping" you guys, esp. @saulspatz because i definitely could not have done this without your numerical evidence!  BTW i would love to see any essentially different proofs.

Comment: @antkam No need to apologize.  I enjoy this site most when I feel like I'm collaborating with someone.  My proof was much less elegant than yours.  I planned to prove by induction that neither HTH...H nor TH....H could be transformed to all heads in the $n=3m+2$ case.  I didn't finish after I saw your slick proof.  I was saying that a move was used once or not at all, so there are two choices for flipping the tail, and than the other moves are forced.  It seems like one of those inductions where you have to prove both statements at once.

Comment: @antkam I'm still working on the problem, though.  In the $2\pmod3$ cases I've looked at, (up through $n=14$) there are two connected components of equal size.  I'm trying to prove this holds in general, but so far, I'm wandering in the wilderness.  If I don't get anywhere, I may post another question.

Comment: @saulspatz - Yes I enjoy collaborating too.  :)  I _think_ the rank $k-1$ comment in my edited post is the way to go, but I have yet to fully convince myself that it is legit.  Roughly: for $k=3n+2, A_k$ does not have full rank.  But $A_{k-1}$ has full rank, and since that is a block inside $A_k$, this means $A_k$ has rank $k-1$.  This should mean $|Range(A_k)| = 2^{k-1}$, completing the proof, but I am not fully familiar with linear algebra of finite field, so I still have to convince myself this argument is legit.

Comment: @antkham Yes, the rank is the dimension of the range, over any field.  I see you've added some stuff since I read your answer.  I'll have to read through it (after dinner).

Comment: @GhazalBadr Since you are new to MSE, you may not realize that if an answer fully answers your question, you should accept it by clicking on the check mark.  This alerts other users that the question has been disposed of.  Personally, I cannot see what more you could want from an answer to this question.

Comment: @antkam What software did you use to compute the inverses mod $2$?

Comment: @saulspatz -- haha, i just used python's linalg.inv.  it turns out $det(A) = 0, 1, -1$ in real numbers!  so the mod2 inverse = abs(real inverse).  if the det were some bigger integer i was gonna multiply the real inverse with det to get an int matrix, then do every entry mod2.  but because det = 0, 1, -1, abs() is easier.

Comment: Another way of showing that the $k=3n+2$ case fails is to choose all the  coins whose position is not a multiple of $3$ and turn them and their neighbours; every coin will get back to its starting position so you cannot get $2^k$ different patterns

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.
I wrote this python script

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import connected_components

for k in range(4,11):
    n=2**k
    masks =  {3}
    j=0
    while 7*2**j < n:
        masks.add(7*2**j)
        j+= 1
    masks.add(n//2+n//4)
    A = np.zeros((n,n), dtype = int)
    for i in range(n):
        for m in masks:
            A[i, i^m] = 1
    supernodes=connected_components(A)
    print(k, supernodes[0])
```

For $4\le k< 11,$ it computes the adjacency matrix of the graph whose vertices are the $k-$bit binary strings, where two vertices are adjacent if one can be transformed into the other by a single flip (substituting $1$'s and $0'$s for heads and tails, of course.)

Then it computes the connected components of the graph.  The problem is possible if and only if the number is one.  Here is the output:

```
4 1
5 2
6 1
7 1
8 2
9 1
10 1
```

<s>The script is very fast, so it can probably be used to determine what the pattern is.</s>  `supernodes[1]` is a list that encodes the components.  For example, when $k=5$ this list is

`[0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0]`

This means that TTTTT is in component $0$, TTTTH and TTTHT are in component $1,$ and so on.  Perhaps one might be able to find a pattern and prove that it is impossible in certain cases, but I'm dubious.

The script bogs down considerably a $k$ increases.  I found that $k=11$ is the only other value below $14$ for which it's impossible.  I got bored waiting for the $k=14$ case to finish.

**EDIT**

I've checked that it's impossible for $n=14$ so now I'm willing to guess that it's possible except when $n\equiv2\pmod3$.  One thing I have verified which may be useful, is that in the impossible cases, there are exactly two connected components, and that if two strings different only in the last character, (or only in the first character, by symmetry) then it is impossible to transform one into the other.

So for example, when $n=5,$ every $4-$character string occurs as a prefix of one word in each component  So far, I haven't figured out how it is decided which components the five-character strings go in.  Here is component $0$:

`['TTTTT', 'TTTHH', 'TTHTT', 'TTHHH', 'THTTH', 'THTHT', 'THHTH', 'THHHT', 'HTTTH', 'HTTHT', 'HTHTH', 'HTHHT', 'HHTTT', 'HHTHH', 'HHHTT', 'HHHHH']`

and here is component $1$:

`['TTTTH', 'TTTHT', 'TTHTH', 'TTHHT', 'THTTT', 'THTHH', 'THHTT', 'THHHH', 'HTTTT', 'HTTHH', 'HTHTT', 'HTHHH', 'HHTTH', 'HHTHT', 'HHHTH', 'HHHHT']`

Given a five-character string over $\{H,T\}$ how can we decide which component it should go in without searching the components?

Comment: thx for your help but how can i wrote it as a mathematical proof?

Comment: @GhazalBadr So far, I have no idea how to turn this into a proof.  I suspect that it can be done except when $k\equiv 2\pmod 3,$ but that's from limited evidence.  As for *why* the graph is connected is some cases, but not others, I haven't the foggiest.  I'm trying to think about what blocks it in the case  $k\equiv 2\pmod 3,$ and hoping that if I can solve that, I can see why it does work in the other cases.

Comment: thanks really for your help

Comment: @GhazalBadr No thanks necessary; the problem's got me hooked.  If we don't solve it, please be sure to post your professor's solutions as an answer.